# How to merge generic object to a class in Typescript definition constructor?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.3

I have

```
interface MyClass {
  do(d: 1 | -1): this
}  

interface MyClassConstructor {
  new<T> (cfg?: T & MyClass): MyClass & T
}

interface Window {
  MyClass: MyClassConstructor
}
```

What went wrong with my definition as I couldn't make the follow work

```
var instance = new MyClass({
  undo: function() { this.do(-1) }
});
```

instance doesn't show Class members properly

[image]

**Edit 1:** I'm using Typescript `2.3.2`. And the definition is to have intellisense in Javascript

**Edit 2:** I'm doing this to have better ideas of what the existing members are when calling `new MyClass({ ... })` in my JS

Comment: What version of TypeScript / compiler settings are you using? I see `'Argument of type '{ undo: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyClass'` with TS 2.3.2. Also, is it not supposed to be `new<T> (cfg?: T): MyClass & T` instead?

Comment: @MattBierner I'm using 2.3.2. Updated the detail in question. How can I see the error ? I'm using it in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instantiate interfaces.
Your interfaces are not being translated into js by compiler so at runtime there's no such thing as `MyClass`.

You'll need to create a class like so:

```
class MyClassImpl implements MyClass {
    do(d: 1 | -1): this {
        return this;
    }

    undo(): this {
        return this.do(-1);
    }
}

var instance = new MyClassImpl();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20do(d%3A%201%20%7C%20-1)%3A%20this%0D%0A%7D%20%20%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20MyClassConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20%3CT%3E(cfg%3F%3A%20T%20%26%20MyClass)%3A%20MyClass%20%26%20T%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Window%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20MyClass%3A%20MyClassConstructor%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClassImpl%20implements%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20do(d%3A%201%20%7C%20-1)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20undo()%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.do(-1)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20instance%20%3D%20new%20MyClassImpl()%3B))

Or you can have it this way:

```
var instance = new class implements MyClass {
    do(d: 1 | -1): this {
        return this;
    }

    undo(): this {
        return this.do(-1);
    }
}();
```

---

#### Edit

If you already have an implementation for `MyClass` then this is what you need:

```
interface MyClass {
    do(d: 1 | -1): this
}  

interface MyClassConstructor {
    new <T>(cfg?: T): MyClass & T
}

declare const MyClass: MyClassConstructor;
```

Comment: I'm using it in Js, the definition is to have intellisense.

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While simplifying it to `<T>(cfg?: T): MyClass & T` does yield the instance all the members, its  not what I wanted to achieve. I was looking for a way to have intellisense in the constructor, not only for new members, but also all of the existing members of `MyClass`. So when I do `new MyClass({ .... })`, I have more clue what to override.

I tried with both `new <T extends MyClass> ....` and the original one in my question but no luck.

Comment: Try `<T extends Partial<MyClass>>`

Comment: It still doesn't work. But when I tried `new <T>(cfg?: T & Partial<MyClass>): MyClass & T`, it works as expected. Beautiful for me, but not sure why extending generic doesn't. Please update your answer so I can mark it as accepted. Thanks for your help.